# Select results where the newest date is the newest

Tags: mysql, date

I have a MySQL table with 2 fields: `id_type` and `created_at`

There are several rows with the same `id_type` and different timestamps. Eg:

```
3   -   2015-06-10 12:01:20
1   -   2015-03-21 04:14:10
0   -   2015-05-06 21:43:00
3   -   2015-05-13 19:34:32
3   -   2015-07-18 03:47:55
```

I need to select, for each `id_type` the row where the `created_at` is the newest.

Expected result:

```
1   -   2015-03-21 04:14:10
0   -   2015-05-06 21:43:00
3   -   2015-07-18 03:47:55
```

I've run into query errors. How should I build it properly?

Comment: see GROUP BY clause and MAX function basics

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `max()` and `group by`

```
select id_type, max(created_at) from test group by id_type
```

see [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4f2a/1)